# Dynamic search bar relative to div

Tags: html, css

[image]

I was curious how this is done, I've made something similar e.g.

```
<div class="header-con">
   <div class="search-bar-con">
       <input type="text" name="search" class="search-bar"> 
       <input type="submit" name="search-submit" class="search-btn">
   </div>

   <div class="function-con">

     <div class="func-btn">Home</div>
     <div class="funct-btn">About</div>

   </div>
</div>
```

The Search bar Container and function container are both relative to each other, using inline-block so they don't break off.

```
  .search-bar-con {
   position: relative;
   left: 0px;
   top: -13px;
   width: 43%;
   height: 80%;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0;
   min-width: 105px;
   padding: 0;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   justify-content: flex-start; 
   margin-left: 10px;
 }

 .function-con {
    position: relative;
    top:10%;
    width: auto;
    height: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

My intention is to keep the function container a fixed width but the search container dynamic in regards to the page width and the position of the function container. At the moment, the function container breaks off the moment there isn't enough room as the search bar doesn't change width enough to leave space. I've been using media queries but isn't as smooth or simple as the gif above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these situations **Flex box** is the best way. In this way the div `.function-con` that must fill the remained space of row, has property `flex: 1;`

```css
.header-con{
   display: flex;
   }
.search-bar-con {
 left: 0px;
 top: -13px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
  

.function-con {
 position: relative;
 top: 10%;
 width: auto;
 height: 80%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 flex: 1;
 display: flex;
 padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-con">
   <div class="search-bar-con">
       <input type="text" name="search" class="search-bar"> 
       <input type="submit" name="search-submit" class="search-btn">
   </div>

   <div class="function-con">

     <div class="func-btn">Home</div>
     <div class="funct-btn">About</div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Probably you want your menus are side by side. If you don't want, remove the `display: flex;` from `div.function-con` .

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change your `min-width: 105px` in `.search-bar-con` into: `max-width: 105px` that does the job. `max-width` is used for scaling on mobile devices, or in this case your browser-window.